# Concatenate Dynamic SQL Columns

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, concatenation

I've got three tables; tblProducts and tblOption and tblOptionValue. (T-SQL)

I get all possible combinations of my product using the this query:

```
DECLARE @ProductId INT, @Query NVARCHAR(MAX), @ProductOptionGroupId INT
SET @ProductId = 69
SET @Query = ''

DECLARE CC CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT OptionID
FROM tblOption
WHERE ProductId = @ProductId

OPEN CC
FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @ProductOptionGroupId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Query = @Query + '(SELECT DISTINCT tblOptionValue.Name FROM tblOptionValue INNER JOIN tblOption on tblOptionValue.OptionID = tblOption.OptionID WHERE tblOptionValue.OptionId='+CAST(@ProductOptionGroupId AS VARCHAR)+'AND tblOption.ProductId='+CAST(@ProductId AS VARCHAR)+
                 +') AS Table' + CAST(@ProductOptionGroupId AS VARCHAR)+' CROSS JOIN '
    FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @ProductOptionGroupId
END
CLOSE CC
DEALLOCATE CC
SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + LEFT(@Query,LEN(@Query)-10) 
PRINT @Query
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757739/how-to-generate-all-possible-data-combinations-in-sql) thanks to @Lamak
I've adapted it to my database but I need to:

A) Find a way to pull all the data back in one column instead of multiple columns
B) Name the tblOptionValue.Name column the same as the associated tblOption.Name field

Any thoughts on how I might achieve the above?

Many thanks

**Update:** I managed to achieve my goals, using the following query:

```
DECLARE @ProductId INT, @Query NVARCHAR(MAX), @ProductOptionGroupId INT, @cName     VARCHAR(300)
SET @ProductId = 70
SET @Query = ''

DECLARE CC CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT OptionID
FROM tblOption
WHERE ProductId = @ProductId

OPEN CC
FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @ProductOptionGroupId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @cName = (SELECT Name FROM tblOption WHERE OptionID=@ProductOptionGroupId)
    SET @Query = @Query + '(SELECT DISTINCT tblOptionValue.Name as '+@cName+' FROM tblOptionValue INNER JOIN tblOption on tblOptionValue.OptionID = tblOption.OptionID INNER JOIN tblProduct on tblOption.ProductID=tblProduct.ProductID WHERE tblOptionValue.OptionId='+CAST(@ProductOptionGroupId AS VARCHAR)+'AND tblOption.ProductId='+CAST(@ProductId AS VARCHAR)+
                 +') AS Table' + CAST(@ProductOptionGroupId AS VARCHAR)+' CROSS JOIN '    
    FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @ProductOptionGroupId
END
CLOSE CC
DEALLOCATE CC
SET @Query = 'SELECT t2.*, t1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM ' + LEFT(@Query,LEN(@Query)-10)
SET @Query = @Query + ') as t1, 
(SELECT * FROM tblProduct WHERE ProductID=70) as t2'

PRINT @Query
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: I really don't see the need for the cursor.

Comment: @ingo thanks for your feedback, I wasn't entirely sure I needed the cursor either. However I have no other idea how to construct my query to achieve what I needed. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Try writing it as a "normal" query. And I'll be glad to help you from there

Comment: If your update is the answer to the question then post it as an answer. You can then mark this question as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the user's solution into an answer.

```
DECLARE @ProductId INT, @Query NVARCHAR(MAX), @ProductOptionGroupId INT, @cName     VARCHAR(300)
SET @ProductId = 70
SET @Query = ''

DECLARE CC CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT OptionID
FROM tblOption
WHERE ProductId = @ProductId

OPEN CC
FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @ProductOptionGroupId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @cName = (SELECT Name FROM tblOption WHERE OptionID=@ProductOptionGroupId)
    SET @Query = @Query + '(SELECT DISTINCT tblOptionValue.Name as '+@cName+' FROM tblOptionValue INNER JOIN tblOption on tblOptionValue.OptionID = tblOption.OptionID INNER JOIN tblProduct on tblOption.ProductID=tblProduct.ProductID WHERE tblOptionValue.OptionId='+CAST(@ProductOptionGroupId AS VARCHAR)+'AND tblOption.ProductId='+CAST(@ProductId AS VARCHAR)+
                 +') AS Table' + CAST(@ProductOptionGroupId AS VARCHAR)+' CROSS JOIN '    
    FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @ProductOptionGroupId
END
CLOSE CC
DEALLOCATE CC
SET @Query = 'SELECT t2.*, t1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM ' + LEFT(@Query,LEN(@Query)-10)
SET @Query = @Query + ') as t1, 
(SELECT * FROM tblProduct WHERE ProductID=70) as t2'

PRINT @Query
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```