# Multiple Combinations of Values in Numerical Order

Tags: t-sql, combinations

I have searched and attempted to solve this puzzle myself (I've gotten close, but I've had no luck). I have a large table of values (composed of Sets of Values) that can have multiple combinations, but those combinations must be returned in the ID order.

I have not been able to get this to work in SQL.

Example Set:

(Sorry I am not able to post an image which would explain it better so Ill keep it simple.)

```
Table[(ID, Value) {(1,A),(1,B),(1,C),(2,D),(3,F),(3,G), (4,J), (5,S),(5,T),(5,U))}

RESULTS
ID   VALUE

1   A
2   F
3   G
4   J
5   S

1   A
2   F
3   G
4   J
5   T

1   A
2   F
3   G
4   J
5   U

1   A
2   F
3   H
4   J
5   S

1   A
2   F
3   H
4   J
5   T

1   A
2   F
3   H
4   J
5   U

1   B
2   F
3   G
4   J
5   S

1   B
2   F
3   G
4   J
5   T

1   B
2   F
3   G
4   J
5   U

1   B
2   F
3   H
4   J
5   S

1   B
2   F
3   H
4   J
5   T

1   B
2   F
3   H
4   J
5   U

1   C
2   F
3   G
4   J
5   S

1   C
2   F
3   G
4   J
5   T

1   C
2   F
3   G
4   J
5   U

1   C
2   F
3   H
4   J
5   S

1   C
2   F
3   H
4   J
5   T

1   C
2   F
3   H
4   J
5   U
```

Comment: Sorry, this is very unclear. Please rewrite to explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish and what you don't understand.

Comment: What you trying to achive? Provide sample code.

Comment: I believe it's like this. Imagine the ID as "seats". Each row says which seat a person( the letter) can sit in. So A,B, and C can sit in seat 1. D in seat 2. Now find all possible combinations

Comment: Stephan you are correct sir. Thank oyu guys and I apologize for not being more clear, I created an image of a spreadsheet example but did not have the ability to upload images. The link Dannyg9090 provided gave me the foundation of what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem in dynamic SQL without any cursors or loops.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('yourTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE yourTable;

CREATE TABLE yourTable (ID INT, Value CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO yourTable
VALUES  (1,'A'),(1,'B'),(1,'C'),
        (2,'D'),
        (3,'F'),(3,'G'),
        (4,'J'),
        (5,'S'),(5,'T'),(5,'U');

DECLARE @row_number_cols    VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Aliased_Cols       VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Cross_Joins        VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Unpivot            VARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT  @row_number_cols =  COALESCE(@row_number_cols + ',','') + col,
        @Aliased_Cols =     COALESCE(@Aliased_Cols + ',','') + CONCAT(col,' AS col',ID),
        @Cross_Joins =      COALESCE(@Cross_Joins,'') + CASE
                                                            WHEN ID = 1 THEN CONCAT(' FROM (SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE ID = 1) AS ID',ID)
                                                            ELSE CONCAT(' CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE ID = ',ID,') AS ID',ID)
                                                        END,
        @Unpivot = COALESCE(@Unpivot + ',','') + CONCAT('col',ID)
FROM yourTable A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONCAT('ID',ID,'.Value')) CA(col) --Just so I can reuse "col" in my code
GROUP BY A.ID,CA.col

SELECT @row_number_cols,@Aliased_Cols,@Cross_Joins,@Unpivot
SELECT
'WITH CTE_crossJoins
AS
(
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @row_number_cols + ') group_num,' + @Aliased_Cols +
@Cross_Joins + '
)

SELECT  group_num,
        val
FROM CTE_crossJoins
UNPIVOT
(
    val for col IN (' + @Unpivot + ')
) unpvt
ORDER BY 1,2'
```

Results:

```
group_num            val
-------------------- ----
1                    A
1                    D
1                    F
1                    J
1                    S
2                    A
2                    D
2                    G
2                    J
2                    S
3                    A
3                    D
3                    G
3                    J
3                    T
4                    A
4                    D
4                    F
4                    J
4                    T
5                    A
5                    D
5                    F
5                    J
5                    U
6                    A
6                    D
6                    G
6                    J
6                    U
7                    B
7                    D
7                    G
7                    J
7                    S
8                    B
8                    D
8                    F
8                    J
8                    S
9                    B
9                    D
9                    F
9                    J
9                    T
10                   B
10                   D
10                   G
10                   J
10                   T
11                   B
11                   D
11                   G
11                   J
11                   U
12                   B
12                   D
12                   F
12                   J
12                   U
13                   C
13                   D
13                   F
13                   J
13                   S
14                   C
14                   D
14                   G
14                   J
14                   S
15                   C
15                   D
15                   G
15                   J
15                   T
16                   C
16                   D
16                   F
16                   J
16                   T
17                   C
17                   D
17                   F
17                   J
17                   U
18                   C
18                   D
18                   G
18                   J
18                   U
```

Comment: Thank you Stephan. You understood what I was trying to accomplish. The link Dannyg9090 provided works and I created a cursor and loop to put them in rows rather than columns. Looking at this I think I can use your code as an example to do the same thing - build Dynamic SQL that does multiple CROSS JOINS (similar with the link Danny gave) and then UNPIVOT which will put them in rows. And it looks much cleaner than what I have.

Comment: I can do this in dynamic SQL without Loops or Cursors as there is no need for them and whenever possible you want to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been answered before here:

[How to generate all possible data combinations in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757739/how-to-generate-all-possible-data-combinations-in-sql)

difference being that they essentially dropped the ID column, should be easy to pull it through though.

Comment: Danny this worked. Thank you and everyone for helping me out.  I very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

You can employ the SQL windows function to achieve this.

```
;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT Id, 
    Value, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) RN 
    FROM Tbl
    )

SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY RN, ID, VALUE
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/830e8/2)

Comment: I'm not sure this is what David is looking for. I think he wants to build every possible combination of the 5 IDs given the values they have.